# Functional javascript read, async, write result

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads

I am reading mostly adequate guide to fp now. But I cannot figure out how to correctly compose this functions.

```
const R = require('ramda');
const {IO, Future} = require('ramda-fantasy');

const read = () => IO(() => 'hello');
const write = (data) => IO(() => {
    console.log(data)
    return data;
});

const process = (data) => Future((reject, resolve) => {
  return setTimeout(() => resolve(data), 0);
});
```

What is the best way to combine functions: read -> process -> write ?

Comment: Is your `process` function actually asynchronous?

Comment: I guess you'd need to write a monad transformer for `IO<Promise<A>>` (or `IO<Future<A>>`), but you'll need to do that by hand in JS

Comment: @Bergi added set timeout for clarity.

Comment: You wouldn't need a monad transformer if you didn't use the `IO` data type. The `IO` data type is quite pointless in JavaScript. In fact, the `Future` or `Promise` data type is the real `IO` data type.

Answer (score 0):

change the ios to futures.

```
const R = require('ramda');
const {Future} = require('ramda-fantasy');

const read = () => Future((reject, resolve) => resolve('hello'));

const write = (data) => Future((reject, resolve) => {
    console.log(data)
    resolve(data);
});

const process = (data) => Future((reject, resolve) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve(data), 0);
});

read.chain(process)
    .chain(write)
    .fork(console.warn, console.log);
```

Futures are like async ios so theres not much point between lifting between the two types. If you really wanted to treat them differently you could nest the monad into IO> as bergi suggested.